# word2vec on POS tags

Tags: python, nltk, word2vec

Please check my code of getting POS vectors.Instead of getting POS tag vectors I am just getting vectors of alphabets in POS.E.g instead of getting POS tags vectors CC,DT,PRP etc I am getting vectors of C,D and P.

```
#get word and pos tagger
def get_pos_tagger(self, document):

    # tokenizer
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(document)
    # get pos tagger
    posTagger = nltk.pos_tag(tokens=tokens)
    tags = []
    for (word, tag) in posTagger:
        tags.append(tag)

    return tags


def get_tag_and_training_data(self):
    tags=[]
    documents=[]
    line_counter=1

    with open(self.filename) as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
        for line in spamreader:
            #Initialize the token list for line
            tags.append(int(line[0]))
            documents.append(line[1].lower() + " " + line[2].lower())

    return tags,documents


# build pos model
def buildPosModel(self):
    tags, documents = self.get_tag_and_training_data()
    sentences = []

    for document in documents:
     sentences += self.get_pos_tagger(document)
     print(sentences)
    modelPos = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, size=100, min_count=1, window=5, workers=cores)
    modelPos.wv.save_word2vec_format('word2vecposmodel.bin', binary=False)
    return modelPos
```

Comment: It's very hard to guess what's going wrong in your code without seeing your code. But maybe, you're passing your word2vec model a sequence-of-strings, instead of the sequence-of-lists-of-strings that it's expecting?

Comment: Please check my code and then tell where I am mistaking.I am badly stuck in it

Comment: What does `print(sentences[0])` show, if placed where you have `print(sentences)`?

Comment: It shows JJ (POS tag) repeating 300-400 times in a column

Comment: Is that waht you expect from your first example text? (If not, there's a problem before feeding data to Word2Vec.)  Does `modelPos['JJ']` return a vector? if so, you're getting training on multicharacter POS tokens, so it's not yet clearly demonstrated what the problem is. (What POS tag are you expecting a vector for – and can you write code that shows that both (1) that tag is in `sentences`; and (2) that tag is NOT in `modelPos`?)

Comment: Print(sentences) gives me all possible tags of my corpus correctly.but when I save the model it gives me the vectors of first alphabet instead of POS tags like it just give me the vector of J non JJ

Comment: Does `modelPos['JJ']` return a vector? What POS tag are you expecting a vector for, and can you write code (and add it to the clearly-formatted question above) that shows that both (1) that tag is really in `sentences` (as one token inside a list-of-tokens); and (2) that tag is not in `modelPos`? Doing this clearly, in code, with well-formatted output, will either reveal a bug in the library (very unlikely) or help illustrate what is wrong in your `sentences` or assumptions.